# Sed replace portions of lines not beginning with http://

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm getting stuck with sed.. I'm trying to prefix links in an html file with a / when they don't start with http.. I'm aware this is possibly not the best way to go about this but I'm just after a simple quick/solution.

So far, I've tried this (note IRL I'll use the -i in place flag etc, this is just for testing):

```
echo '<a href="egww">blah</a><a href="http://bloge.weg">yeah</a>' |
sed 's@href="[^http]@href="/@g'
```

This almost works:

```
<a href="/gww">blah</a><a href="http://bloge.weg">yeah</a>
```

Except the first character of the first link has got cut off, also I think it's not not matching on h,t,t or p rather than the entire string http:

```
echo '<a href="egww">blah</a><a href="p/bloge.weg">damn</a>' |
sed 's@href="[^http]@href="/@g'

<a href="/gww">blah</a><a href="p/bloge.weg">damn</a>
```

I'm pretty stumped at this point, unfortunately google doesn't help much here as negation with sed is generally used for removing lines that contain a string rather than not matching substrings in lines.. I tried several 'normal' regexp patterns but these don't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies for the double negative :p

Answer (score 5):

`[^http]` is not *anything but `http`*. That RE matches one character as long as it's neither `h`, nor `t`, nor `p`. So `href="[^http]` matches `href="b` in `href="blah"`, but not `href="t` in `href="toto"`.

Here, you'd want something like:

```
sed -E 's@(href=")([^h]|h([^t]|t([^t]|t([^p]|$)|$)|$)|$)@\1/\2@g'
```

That is `href="` followed by either not-`h` (a character other than `h`), or `h`-not-`t`, or `ht`-not-`t`, or `htt`-not-`p`, or `htt`-EOL, or `ht`-EOL or `h`-EOL or EOL. (EOL == "end of line", those last 4 unlikely to be found in the input as that would mean the `"` is not matched).

(assuming your `sed` supports the not-yet-standard `-E` option).

You could also add the `/` always but remove it after when in `href="/http`:

```
sed 's@href="@&/@g;s@href="/http@href="http@g'
```

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's|href="\K(?!http)|/|g'
```

Using `perl`'s negative look-ahead RE operator.

Comment: I didn't really understand most of your answer, but the idea of using sed twice worked! That is also much easier to understand :) Thanks!

Comment: How is -E different from -r, i thought it was just the OSX version?

Comment: @User112638726, -r is the GNU (inexplicable) variant. -E is supported by FreeBSD, OS/X and GNU and scheduled for inclusion in the next major version of the POSIX/Unix spec.